# d3 SVG size is much bigger than what I am setting it as when i publish it on Sharepoint

Tags: d3.js, svg, sharepoint, transform, scale

I have tried searching for an answer to this problem but have not been able to find anything that defines my problem.

I have created an Interactive Tree Diagram Menu for my Sharepoint site using D3.js and HTML (Code Below)

In Codepen it works fine and I can adjust the width and length of the SVG using the width and length variables:

```
// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

But no matter what I seem to enter in as the height, once I open this up in a browser the SVG is at least 500px high and taking up way too much empty space.

when I publish this on my Sharepoint site via an iframe, the white space can be even bigger.

I have tried setting the iframe width and height dimensions to 500px, 300px, 100% 50% etc. but it doesn't solve the problem, all it does is mean that you have to scroll within the iframe.

[image: screenshot of size]

I think it may have something to do with the transform/translate settings in the d3 code but I just can't figure it out - any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var treeData =
  {
    "name": "Board", "url":"Site/Board/SitePages/Home.aspx",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "Executive",
        "url":"Site/Board/Executive/SitePages/Home.aspx",
        "children": [
          { "name": "CEO's Office",
  "url":"hSite/Board/Executive/CEO/SitePages/Home.aspx"
          },
          { "name": "Legal & Integrity",
 "url":"Site/Board/Executive/LI/SitePages/Home.aspx",},       
          { "name": "Communications & Stakeholder Relations",
 "url":"Site/Board/Executive/CGR/SitePages/Home.aspx",},
          { "name": "People & Culture",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/PC/SitePages/Home.aspx",
          "children": [
            {"name": "Health, Safety, Environment & Wellbeing",
              "url":"Site/Board/Executive/PC/HSEW/SitePages/Home.aspx"
            }]},
          {"name": "Finance & Risk",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FR/SitePages/Home.aspx",
          "children": [
            {"name":"Financial Risk Register",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FR/FIN/SitePages/Home.aspx"}
          ]
          },
          {"name":"Volunteers & Strategy",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/VS/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
          {"name":"Infrastructure Services",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/IS/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
          {"name":"Fire & Emergency Management",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/SitePages/Home.aspx",
          "children":[
            {"name":"Bushfire Portfolio",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/BP/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
            {"name":"Capability & Growth Portfolio",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/CGP/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
            {"name":"Regional Services Portfolio",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/RSP/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
            {"name":"Training Portfolio",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/TP/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
            {"name":"Urban Portfolio",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/UP/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
            {"name":"South West Region",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/SW/SitePages/Home.aspx",
            "children":[
              {"name":"District 04",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/SW/D04/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 05",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/SW/D05/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 06",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/SW/D06/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 07",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/SW/D07/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
            ]
            },
            {"name":"West Region",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/W/SitePages/Home.aspx",
            "children":[
              {"name":"District 15",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/W/D15/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 16",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/W/D16/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 17",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/W/D17/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
            ]
            },
            {"name":"North West Region",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/NW/SitePages/Home.aspx",
            "children":[
              {"name":"District 02",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/NW/D02/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 14",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/NW/D14/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 18",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/NW/D18/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 20",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/NW/D20/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
            ]
            },
            {"name":"North East Region",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/NE/SitePages/Home.aspx",
            "children":[
              {"name":"District 12",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/NE/D12/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 13",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/NE/D13/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 22",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/NE/D22/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 23",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/NE/D23/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 24",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/NE/D24/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
            ]
            },
            {"name":"South East Region",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/SE/SitePages/Home.aspx",
            "children":[
              {"name":"District 08",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/SE/D08/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 09",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/SE/D09/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 10",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/SE/D10/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 11",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/SE/D11/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
              {"name":"District 27",
           "url":"Site/Board/Executive/FEM/SE/D27/SitePages/Home.aspx"},
            ]
            },
          ]
          }
          
        ]
      }
      ]
      };

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("#Menu").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    });

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "#bdc3c7" : "#fff";
      })
      .on('click', click);

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".30em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; })
      .attr('class','normalText')
      .on('click', hyperclick)
      .on('mouseover', function(d,i) {
            d3.select(this)
            .attr('class', 'bigText')
            .style('fill','#c0392b')
            ;})
  .on('mouseout', function(d,i) {
            d3.select(this)
            .attr('class', 'normalText')
            .style('fill','black')
            ;});
      
  function hyperclick(d) {
        window.open(d.data.url);
    }
  


  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "#bdc3c7" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<style>
 
  .node circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #c0392b;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.bigText {
    font-family: Sans-Serif;  
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #e74c3c;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-style: bold;
  }
  
 .normalText {
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
  } 
  
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #95a5a6;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-length: 1px;
}
</style>  
</head>
<body>
<div id="heading"></div>
<div id="Instructions"></div>
<div id="Menu"></div>
<script>



</script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

******** BONUS Question **********

Anyone who can tell me to set it up so that three levels of the collapsible tree diagram are shown by default instead of 2 will be awarded 10 internet points!

Comment: Have you tried setting the svg width and height attributes to 100%, and then set the width/height of the containing div (not the iframe)? This seems to provide consistent results for me. For example, I changed your JS to: `var svg = d3.select("#Menu").append("svg").attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "100%").append("g").attr("transform", "translate("+ margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");` and added `#Menu { width: 960px; height: 300px;  }` to your styles.

Comment: @odin243 this worked a treat - thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have you tried setting the svg width and height attributes to 100%,
>   and then set the width/height of the containing div (not the iframe)?
>   This seems to provide consistent results for me. For example, I
>   changed your JS to: var svg =
>   d3.select("#Menu").append("svg").attr("width", "100%").attr("height",
>   "100%").append("g").attr("transform", "translate("+ margin.left + ","
>   + margin.top + ")"); and added #Menu { width: 960px; height: 300px; } to your styles. – odin243 Dec 21 at 21:25

This worked a treat